# How to get pull requests on Github repositories depending on programming language for a specific location

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to retrieve data on the languages used in Github repos overtime for a specific location. For example, what languages are used in repos based in the UK and how has that changed over time.

Essentially I would like to create a visualisation similar to this one created by Githut - https://madnight.github.io/githut/#/pull_requests/2017/4

Only difference is location - how could I go about doing that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "what languages are used in repos based in the UK" repositories don't have locations, only users have this optionnal info. Do you mean pull request created by user located in the uk ?

Comment: @BertrandMartel Yes, but by language. What languages are people either pushing or pulling (whichever one) from Github in the UK ? How can I get that?

Comment: can you update the question wording accordingly

Comment: @BertrandMartel done! now can I get some help please